# 'Previously' or 'ever ' in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I encountered a question in a textbook for an English exam as below where I did not understand why the correct answer is that.

> Ms.Tanaka is the ideal leader for the project because she has _______
>   worked in both business management and textile design.
>   (A) yet
>   (B) especially
>   (C) previously
>   (D) ever

The answer was (C) according to the book but it feels like (D) is also possible. Why is (D) not correct?

Comment: _Ever_ is a negative polarity item and therefore cannot be used outside the scope of a negative. There is no negative in the example, so _ever_ would be ungrammatical.

Comment: @JohnLawler But, you can say 'the best I have ever seen,' even though there is no negative meaning in it.

Comment: Superlatives (and comparatives, and questions, and many other constructions) can trigger negative polarity. See the list of [English NPIs and Negative triggers here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Comment: I would say *already* suits much better.

Comment: @Kris But that's not one of the choices.

Comment: I could conceive in informal contexts, of a sentence, "Ms.Tanaka is the ideal leader for the project. Has she ever worked in business management and textile design!" But that's cheating.

Comment: @DavidPugh I suspect it's because it's the direct translation of a word that would fit in his native language. Isn't that where misuses like this often come from?

Answer (score 1):

If you go through the definitions of [*ever*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ever) you'll see that none of them really fit this context.

> [USUALLY WITH NEGATIVE OR IN QUESTIONS] At any time

This isn't a negative or a question.

> Used in comparisons for emphasis

This isn't a comparison.

> At all times; always

This initially seems like it could be used. However, this sense tends to be part of set phrases, such as *as ... as ever*, *happily ever after*, and *forever and ever*.

> [WITH COMPARATIVE] Increasingly; constantly

It's not modifying a comparative.

> Used for emphasis in questions expressing astonishment or outrage

It's not in a question, nor is it expressing any significant emotion.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence makes sense without the adverb:

> Ms.Tanaka is the ideal leader for the project because she has worked
>   in both business management and textile design.

Which adverb modifies the declarative verb meaningfully?

> (C) *[previously](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/previously)*
>
> adverb
>
> At a previous or earlier time; before:

*Previous* experience is a major factor in measuring qualification for leadership, and according to the *[corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20previously%20worked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20previously%20worked%3B%2Cc0)*, *previous* has quite a strong idiomatic connection to this declarative verb form *has worked*:

[image]

*Ever* has idiomatic connection to the phrase *has worked*, but according to the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20ever%20worked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20ever%20worked%3B%2Cc0) the connection is mainly in interrogative, relative and conditional constructions:

> - Who has ever worked in any hospital or medical facility?
> - Sir Clive Woodward singled him out as the best he has ever worked with...
> - The first thing the troubleshooter does is find out if the equipment has
>     ever worked.

According to the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20yet%20worked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20yet%20worked%3B%2Cc0), *yet* is used with the declarative verb phrase mainly in negative contexts:

> - Enormous sums have been spent on huge fusion generators, but none has yet worked as a power source.

According to the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20especially%20worked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20especially%20worked%3B%2Cc0), *especially* and have very little idiomatic use with the declarative phrase *has worked*: